# Let $a\gt 2 $ be a root of the equation $x^3-x-8 = 0$. Compute $\sqrt[3]{6a^2-13a} + \sqrt[3]{6a^2+13a+16}$

Tags: algebra-precalculus, contest-math

I came across this question in some past contest prep papers belonging to Akdeniz University. To solve it, I've tried letting the cuberoots equal some $k$ and $l$ and tried writing $k+l$ in terms of $kl$ and $k^3+l^3$ but to no avail. Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Are you sure it's not the root of the equation $x^3-x-8=0$? Then the answer is $4$...

Comment: omg i'm so sorry haha i fixed it now. could you please explain how you got the answer?

Comment: $(a+2)^3 = a^3 + 6a^2 + 12a + 8 =  6a^2 + 13a + 16$ and $(-a+2)^3 = -a^3 + 6a^2 - 12a + 8 =  6a^2 - 13a$.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Using $a^3-a-8=0$ one gets:

$$(2+a)^3=a^3+6a^2+12a+8=(a^3-a-8)+6a^2+13a+16=6a^2+13a+16$$

$$(2-a)^3=-a^3+6a^2-12a+8=-(a^3-a-8)+6a^2-13a=6a^2-13a$$

So $\sqrt[3]{6a^2+13a+16}+\sqrt[3]{6a^2-13a}=2+a+2-a=4$

Comment: Note: You may wonder how did I come up with $2+a$ and $2-a$. I simply wrote $\sqrt[3]{6a^2+13a+16}=\alpha+\beta a$, $\sqrt[3]{6a^2-13a}=\alpha-\beta a$. Then I rose both equalities to the third power, added them together and found $\alpha$ and $\beta$ by identifying the coefficients.